# Remove CDATA tags when importing HTML into Sharepoint

Tags: xml, import, wiki-pages

I want to import HTML into Sharepoint AS HTML. Right now, Sharepoint is wrapping my text in CDATA tags.

I'm creating an enterprise wiki page, then assigning `$wikiPage["PublishingPageContent"] = $pageContent`. Is there a way to not allow Sharepoint to wrap CDATA tags around my content?

The full script is [here](http://pastebin.com/rk5FpiN5).